# I have two circuits, how will the second one interact with the first one?

Tags: ac, circuits

Suppose we have 2 circuits :

One is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f25aGQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We call that a circuit.

And the second is this :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX2ak6.png)</sup>

How will the 2nd circuit react to the 1st circuit? Here's what I think it should happen.

Since the current in the 1st is alternating , the magnetic field created by the coil will also constantly changing direction and strength ( direction every 2/f sc and strength constantly)

When the magnetic field of the 1st circuit hits the wire of the 2nd circuit an alternating current will be induced ( due to the costant change of strength and direction of magnetic field in the 1st circuit).

The natural frequency of the tuning circuit(L1,C1) will not be the same with the frequency of induced alternating current cause big reactance -> big impendance -> low average current.

Since we have a half wave rectifier connected parralel to a diode every 2/f sc the mic will 'beep' in a periodic fashion.

Is that correct?

Comment: How are the two circuits connected? At the moment circuit 2 does not have a supply...

Comment: It doesn't need for a battery supply due to Faraday's law.

Comment: Wel.. it sort of has. The speaker can function as source. My father told me he used a speaker as microphone in the 40's.

Comment: Currents are not induced by magnetism. Voltages are induced by magnetism.

Comment: So if voltage is induced current wont be created?

Comment: Nice toxicity . How do electric generators work then? A varying magnetic field hits a wire plainly simple.

Comment: A non-zero sum voltage between 2 points creates a current?(in a closed loop) Agree?

Comment: Current IS NOT induced but current will flow due to the induced voltage and a circuital path for current to flow.

Comment: Well its pretty obvious since we have a closed loop here.

Comment: Have you actually read any of the wikipedia links I gave you yesterday?  Did my comments about inductive transmitters not make sense?

Comment: This question is about understanding of electric circuit , it has nothing to do with transmitters/receivers.

Comment: *Well its pretty obvious since we have a closed loop here* - listen to me and listen good. With engineering of all branches the devil is in the detail and, some of that detail is using the right terminology and not calling things by the wrong name. "Current is induced" is one of those details that is a hindrance to development so stop being so blasé about it. Speakers don't beep either (car horns beep). Also, what does this mean: *Since we have a half wave rectifier connected parralel to a diode*??

Comment: A diode is a half wave rectifier with alternating voltage. Half cycle it is forward biased , half cycle is reverse biased ( recovery time is neglible compared to the period of oscillation of voltage).

Comment: @JellyStrawberry no, it's not. A diode is a diode. A half-wave rectifier is what you build out of it. Seriously, same statement as to one of your previous questions: get a good textbook. Your communication skills with respects to electronics are so bad that we can't even help you.

Comment: @JellyStrawberry:   It most certainly is about transmitting and receiving.  You have one circuit driven by a signal generator.  You have another with out its own power source, and you ask hoq the two will interact.  The only way the two can interact is for the circuit with the signal generator to act as a transmitter and for the other circuit to act as a receiver.

Comment: @JellyStrawberry instead of asking more of these really unfocused questions, do some searching on crystal sets and reading, online or books (search "ladybird book transistor radio" for one, maybe get some parts and build one but based on a real proven design. Asking questions about that might be on topic.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a look at what those circuits will do when built and driven as shown.

Since both are thrown together from random components, I tossed them both together with whatever random components I found in my junk box.

- Inductors: two rolls of wire each of about 450µH inductance - more or less.  I measured one at about 466µH.  The other is missing a couple of meters so its inductance will be lower.
- Capacitor: I pulled a couple of 0.04µF capacitors out of a scrap PCB and soldered them in parallel to make a 0.08µF capacitor.
- Diode:  some small signal diode from the same PCB the capacitors came from.
- Microphone:  you'd normally use a speaker to hear things.  I used an earphone.  I have no idea of the impedance.
- Signal generator: I slapped together an audio signal generator using a pair of powered speakers and [purr data](https://agraef.github.io/purr-data/) running on my PC to do the actual sound generation.  The speakers have an amplified output that can deliver a couple of watts of power.

The circuits look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwTN54.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

"Thing 1" is just a coil connected to my signal generator.  I left out the resistor because that would only reduce the power to the coil - and the coil is going to need all the power it can get.

"Thing 2" is the OP's "circuit 2" modified to reflect what I really used.

I made a few measurements at the indicated spots, using the respective ground for each circuit.

This is at the "TX" flag of "thing 1:"

[image]

No surprises there.  That's a 1000 hertz signal at the maximum amplitude my speaker amplifier can produce without obvious distortion.

This is the the voltage at the spot marked "RX" in "thing 2:"

[image]

Again no great surprises.  That's a 1kHz signal, and at a lower amplitude than measured on "thing 1."

Now to the voltage at "RX diode," which is the part the question actually asked about:

[image]

This is not what the question stated should happen.  It is, however, not terribly surprising.  The earphone pretty much bypasses the diode, and we end up with a slightly distorted version of the 1kHz signal at a slightly lower amplitude.  The diode might as well not even be there - or the capacitor, either for that matter.

In the end, the OP's circuit 2 could be replaced by this circuit and perform better:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1pWo5.png)</sup>

That is a simple inductive transmitter with a simple inductive receiver.  It works well, if you can afford to throw piles of power at it.  With the two coils literally laying on each other, the received signal is loud and clear - with a couple of watts driving the transmit coil.

If I move the coils just 20 centimeters apart, the signal becomes almost inaudible.

An AM receiver contains almost the same parts, but the arrangement of the circuit and the exact values of the components makes a world of difference.

It would be better to start from a known [circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio) for a simple AM receiver than randomly string parts together in hopes of hitting on a functional combination.

Comment: Wait a minute . Shouldn't the diode when forward biased get all current from the microphone? Maybe if I put a 100 Ohm resistor then it should work...

Comment: I'm still not sure why you insist on using a microphone.  Regardless, the circuit does what it does.  The resistance of the speaker is much lower than that of the diode, and the current goes through it rather than the diode.  The same thing happens if you use a resistor instead of the speaker.  I tried it with a 7500 ohm resistor instead of the speaker.  Same response.

Comment: Have you considered trying to build any of this stuff yourself?  As you can see, I didn't use anything expensive or hard to get.  Amplified speakers for connecting to a PC are cheap and common, the parts are scrounged out of junk, and the wire is just plain old solid core telephone wire.

Comment: The electronics store of my town doesn't have any of those...

Comment: Is the resistance lower even when the diode is forward biased ? How is this possible?

Comment: A forward biased diode isn't a short circuit.

Comment: Ok ill try a circuit with diode tomorrow ( will be busy for rest of day ) and comment on this.

Comment: Look this : https://circuitglobe.com/resistance-of-a-diode.html      '' In other words an actual diode offers a very small resistance (not zero) when forward biased and is called a forward resistance.''